# I am sending a action button over webhook in slack which is not visible in the MAC slack app

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am sending a action button over webhook in slack which is not visible in the MAC slack app, 
but i am able to see the same button for the same message on the slack android app...
Is this some kind of bug in the slack app for MAC or is there any setting i am missing to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Slack is platform agnostic, so the API has no platform related settings and all platform related rendering is handled by the respective Slack client. So, if you have don't see a button on your MAC client that is visible via other clients (with the same user) this looks like a bug.

To confirm please also check via Slack's browser client on your MAC.

Then your best action is contact the slack team directly and report the bug.

Comment: Not able to see the buttons in slack browser client as well